# php mongodb '$or' regex search

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

i'm trying to query mongodb "videos" collection to find results by "title" or "tags" fields... it keeps returning 0 results even when i search for terms i know are in the title and/or tags... any help would be appreciated

```
<?php
$user_query = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ", $_GET['q']);
$arr_query = explode(' ', $user_query);

foreach ($arr_query as $q) {
    $title[] = '/'. $q .'/i';
    $tags[] = '/'. $q .'/i';
}
$who=array(
   '$or' => array(
        array('$in' => array('$regex' => $title)),
        array('$in' => array('$regex' => $tags))
            )
    );

$vids=$videos->find($who);
?>
```

Comment: I don't if it's on purpose but in `'$or'` `$or` won't be read as a variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify some fields for your `$in`:

```
$who=array('$or' => array(
    array('somefield' => array('$in' => array(new MongoRegex($title)))),
    array('otherotherfield' => array('$in' => array(new MongoRegex($tags))))
));
```

So it works by saying saying: *if some field is in a range of some values*

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/

#### Edit

That might still not work because of the embedded `$regex`. If this is the case then you can try:

```
$who=array('$or' => array(
    array('somefield' => new MongoRegex($title)),
    array('otherotherfield' => new MongoRegex($tags))
));
```

#### Edit

If either of those queries don't work you can do:

```
$who = array('$or' => array());

foreach($arr_query as $q){
    $who['$or'][] = array('title' => new MongoRegex("/^$q/"));
    $who['$or'][] = array('tags' => new MongoRegex("/^$q/"));
}
```

Something like that should work, again it is untested but if my memory serves me right that should do it.

#### Another edit

This works perfectly for me:

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->tstvid;
$videos = $db->videos;

$videos->insert(array('title' => 'test1', 'tags' => array('h','h')));
$videos->insert(array('title' => 'test2', 'tags' => array('h','h')));
$videos->insert(array('title' => 'test3', 'tags' => array('h','h')));
$videos->insert(array('title' => 'tst3', 'tags' => array('h','test')));

$user_query = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ", "test");
$arr_query = explode(' ', $user_query);

if (count($arr_query) > 1) {

    $who = array(
        '$or' => array()        
    );

    foreach ($arr_query as $q) {
        $who['$or'][] = array('title' => new MongoRegex("/^". $q ."/i"));
        $who['$or'][] = array('title' => new MongoRegex("/^". $q ."/i"));
    }

} else {
    $regex=new MongoRegex("/^". $user_query ."/i");
    $tregex=new MongoRegex("/^". $user_query ."/i");
    $who=array(
                '$or' => array(
                    array('title' => $regex),
                    array('tags' => $tregex)
                    )
            );
}

$vids=$videos->find($who);
$results="";
$i=0;
foreach($vids as $vid){
    $results .= "<li>".$vid['title']."</li>\n";
    $i++;
}
if($i==0){
    $results="<em>No results found</em>";
}

echo $results;
```

And it outputs:

```
test1
test2
test3
tst3
```

So I am unsure what is wrong but I would recommend double checking your script is breaking up the keywords right and the schema is being searched right by issuing these queries in the console as well.

It should be noted I also tried this with:

```
$user_query = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ", "test h");
```

And it worked as well.

Comment: @b747fp Yea I think it is because you can't nest $regex in a $in, I thought you couldn't but I had no way of testing here. You will most likely need to rewrite your query to remove the $in. Since your query is only looking for one value for each field tyou can probably just take out the $in

Comment: @b747fp Also it is the Mongo regex object, here a sec

Comment: it's not looking for 1 value for each field tho... it's looking for an array of values (each word separately from $_GET['q'])

Comment: @b747fp If my edit does not work (edited the first query to the mongo regex object) then you could build a big $or of each condition checking for a value from the array.

Comment: I tried that too. this is also returning 0 results http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=M4tRuNiF

Comment: @b747fp The else in the `if (count($arr_query) > 1) {` should work, but your if won't, let me edit

Comment: no. the else is not working either. if i enter just 1 keyword that i know is in a title field, it still shows 0 results... both title and tags fields are "strings" if that makes a difference?

Comment: if i get rid of the '$or' part and just do 1 field (title -or- tag by themselves) the search works. but i need it to search both fields =\

Comment: Hmm I just ran the script I added above, it worked perfectly for me. I don't think the PHP is your problem, I think there is another problem afoot. I also tried it with two keywords

Comment: right now im getting an error "invalid regular expression operator"

Comment: could it be because my "tags" field is just comma-separated string? not an array?

Comment: No it should be able to search comma separated, here I'll post that too, however I changed the second title to tags, no difference for me it worked, may I ask what PHP driver is this?

Comment: I just tried with a comma delimited string, exact same results. Hmm can you run `phpinfo` and search a `mongo` section and tell me the version it says there?

Comment: ok thanks it is working now with your code. i wonder what the problem was... hmmm

Comment: Probably some dodgy array assignment, anyway glad it is working :)

Comment: i did have to remove the ^  in the regex tho for it to work properly on my tests...

Comment: Yes the ^ means from the start of the string, so it might be that the words do no occur at the start of the string

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_GET['q']);
$search_string = $search_string;

    //Connecting mongoDB
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'yourdbname';
    $port = '27017';

    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->$dbname;

    if($m){
        // select a collection
        $videos = $db->videos;

        // search for title and tags 
        $searchQuery = array(
            '$or' => array(
                array(
                    'title' => array(
                        '$regex' => $search_string,
                        ),
                    ),
                array(
                    'tags' => array(
                        '$regex' => $search_string,
                        ),
                    ),
                )
            );

        $cursor = $videos->find($searchQuery);

        foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
            var_dump($doc);
            //or what ever you want
            //var_dump($doc['title']);
        }

    else{
       echo "Collection videos cant select :( <br>";die();
    }
```

Thinks this will help. :D