# $regex with $nin

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I need results from my collection where the field user_id (a string) does not have `abc` or `def` anywhere in it.  Here's what I tried:

```
$regex_array = array("/abc/", "/def/");
$cursor = $colection->find(array('user_id'=> array('$nin'=> $regex_array)));
$cursor = $colection->find(array('user_id'=> array('$regex'=> array('$nin'=> $regex_array))));
```

When I iterate over the cursor, I'm finding that it is still allowing `abc` and `def` as substrings in the results.

Any other way to express the said query?

Comment: Regex is not supported in a `$in` or `$nin` yet so the other way is with an `$and` on all the fields. You could use a regex or with `(d|df)` where d and df represent your words as well

Comment: Do you mean not supported for php driver? coz mongo docs have [a mention](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/) of combining them somehow

Comment: That just shows how you can combine one regex and a `nin` or `in` clause, not how you can make a set of `nin`s based opn regexes.

Comment: getting some hints from @Sammaye's comment and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023821/php-mongodb-or-regex-search?rq=1). Perhaps i'll need to use new MongoRegex()

Comment: MongoRegex is the regex operator for PHP, basically it is exactly what is not supported within the `in` or `nin`

Comment: yes, this worked- Using loop to fill - `$regex_array[] = array('user_id'=> array('$regex'=> new MongoRegex("/whatever/"));` where whatever is replaced by abc and def during the loop. Then `find(array('$nor'=> $regex_array));` Thanks to @Sammaye

Answer (score 2):

Instead of testing multiple regexes, you can combine several regexes into one:

```
/regex1/ or /regex2/
```

translates to

```
/(?:regex1)|(?:regex2)/
```

Comment: One word of caution, there have been unexplained speed problems with using the regex version of grouped or `|`, but it depends on data set

Comment: @Sammaye: Unexplained? How do you mean?

Comment: Of course this regex will use no index which is the explained speed problems but then we have had a couple of threads on the user group where using this kind of regex has resulted in a query much slower than normal regex not using an index. It seems dataset dependant but I thought I would just note it.

Comment: @Sammaye: Thanks. Could you clarify what you mean by an index in the context of a regular expression?

Comment: Theres a pretty complete explanation at the bottom here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/ basically non-prefixed regexes have the problem that MongoDB cannot reliably use an index for them